# XFCE: image as whole applications menu button, not just icon

Tags: x11, xfce, icons, menu

This is what I want for my applications menu, the whole thing, not just the icon that should sit behind the optional text:

[image]

What I get when I change the icon is:

[image]

But what I want is this (edited in GIMP):

[image]

How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your image is scaled down to fit the configured icon size for that label.
The configured size is a square, while the icon is not, so it's heavily padded.

It should work after you configure the icon size to be of a similar shape rectangle, ideally the same size;
The name of the icons size property for that menu icon is `panel-applications-menu` - you could add `:panel-applications-menu=48,24` to the config key `/Gtk/IconSizes`,
see http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=4676 and http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6576 .

Comment: What about for the Whisker Menu?